# Cannot get the phone number in Xamarin Android Programatically in Android 6.0 marshmallow

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This code is not working for Android 6.0 MarshMallow

It returns the empty string.I have given all the permissions

but its not working

```
            TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
           var contact = mTelephonyMgr.Line1Number;
```

Comment: If it is returning an empty string (and not a `null` or a runtime permission exception) then that is what the OS is providing on the device (is it a dual sim device? is the SIM card valid and registered/paid for service?). I would try another device.

Answer (score 0):

> `Only Some countries SIM_CARDS comes with hard coded MOBILE_NUMBER`, It will provide you line1 or line2 numbers if available. I have also tried it before in my current project, I wanted to auto fill users mobile number on registration field...

Comment: Yes you from india too.., No... indian network operators do not provides Mobile numbers hard coded on their SIMs..